# How to modify an array of strings in C inside a function

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, c-strings

I'm having a really hard time trying something super simple in other languages. But in C I was given an exercise that says:

> Write a function that receives an array of strings and modify it based
> on user input.

My code so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define GEN 3
void fillGenes(char **);

int main() {
    char *genes[GEN] = {"Gen0", "Gen1", "Gen2"};
    
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
       printf("%s\n", genes[i]);
    }
    fillGenes(genes);
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
       printf("%s\n", genes[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}

void fillGenes(char **genes) {
    printf("Introduce the name of %d genes.\n", GEN);
    for(int i = 0; i < GEN; i++) {
        printf ("Name of gene %d\n", i);
        char newVal[10];
        scanf("%s", newVal);
        genes[i] = newVal;
    }
}
```

This is wrong, as stated by @Eugene Sh:
`newVal` is array local to the function, after the function is returned, `genes` will be an array of dangling pointer:

```
genes[i] = newVal;
```

The thing is that I cannot `strcpy` as it is [invalid](https://overiq.com/c-programming-101/array-of-pointers-to-strings-in-c/). How can I make this thing to work?

Comment: `newVal` is an array local to the function (actually, even  worse - to the block that is inside the `for` loop). Once the function is returned, your `genes` will contain an array of dangling pointers.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Oh yes, that's the point. But I cannot perform a `strcpy`. Let me rephrase the question, I would like to solve this.

Comment: You can't `strcpy` because the array `genes` is initially containing pointers to *string literals* which cannot be written to. So you either define it as something like `char genes[GEN][MAX_LEN];` to be able to overwrite the strings, or use dynamic allocation to overwrite the pointers.

Comment: `char *genes[GEN] = {"Gen0", "Gen1", "Gen2"};` is not a modifiable array of strings. `genes[i] = newVal;` This is not how string assignment works. Also you cannot point at local arrays and return a pointer to one from a function. All of these issues are best studied by reading a good C programming book.

Comment: You are not supposed to modify the initial question with the solution. It is invalidating the answers and comments. Rolling back the edits..

Comment: Okay, sorry. You are right

Answer (score 2):

Problems:

- Pointers at string literals do not point at modifiable memory, they are read-only.
- You cannot return a pointer to a local array from a function.
- You need to copy strings using `strcpy` or equivalent.

The easiest way to salvage the existing code might be to use the `strdup` function, which is essentially a combination of `malloc` + `strcpy`.

(`strdup` is at the time this is written not yet standard C, but will be later this year in the upcoming C23 release. For now you should be able to find it in `string.h` unless you compile with strict compiler settings.)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define GEN 3
void fillGenes(char **);

int main() {
    char *genes[GEN] = // assign the pointers to read/writeable dynamic memory:
    { 
      strdup("Gen0"), 
      strdup("Gen1"), 
      strdup("Gen2")
    }; 
    
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
       printf("%s\n", genes[i]);
    }
    fillGenes(genes);
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
       printf("%s\n", genes[i]);
       free(genes[i]); // clean up when done using the data
    }
    return 0;
}

void fillGenes(char **genes) {
    printf("Introduce the name of %d genes.\n", GEN);
    for(int i = 0; i < GEN; i++) {
        printf ("Name of gene %d\n", i);
        char newVal[10];
        scanf("%s", newVal);

        free(genes[i]); // clean up not to create a memory leak
        genes[i] = strdup(newVal); // create a new read/writeable copy of the local string
    }
}
```

Comment: "Pointers at string literals do not point at modifiable memory, they are read-only." --> more like "Modifying a _string literal_ is UB.".  Attempting to modify a string literal might work - its UB.

Comment: `scanf("%s", newVal);` too much like `gets()`.  Suggest `scanf("%9s", newVal);`

Answer (score 1):

You could accomplish this by editing a few parts of your code.

```
void fillGenes(char *genes[GEN][10])
```

The `[]` and `*` operator have precedence over the `()`, so it means the pointer to an array of 10 char.
Change it to this:

```
void fillGenes(char (*genes)[10])
```

And this:

```
fillGenes(&genes);
```

to this:

```
fillGenes(genes);
```

remove the `&` since it's already an array.

I would also recommend switching out `scanf` with `fgets`

You could accomplish that by removing this:

```
scanf("%s", genes[i]);
```

and adding this:

```
fgets(genes[i], 10, stdin);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to accomplish this. One of the ways is this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define GEN 3
void fillGenes(char **);
void fillGenes(char **genes) {
    printf("Introduce the name of %d genes.\n", GEN);
    for(int i = 0; i < GEN; i++) {
        printf ("Name of gene %d\n", i);
        char newVal[10];
        scanf("%s", newVal);
        genes[i]=calloc(100, 1);
        strcpy(genes[i], newVal); 
    }
}
int main() {
    char *genes[GEN] = {"Gen0", "Gen1", "Gen2"};
    
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
       printf("%s\n", genes[i]);
    }
    fillGenes(genes);
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
       printf("%s\n", genes[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

By allocating memory and copying the contents of newVal to your array, you avoid making the mistake of having your pointers all point to newVal instead.